Disallow debit cards from googlepay api popup integration
I am working on googlepay api integration as a payment wallet option for our payment page.
My requirement is such that we should only allow credit cards for selection in popup window.( only want to accept the credit card payment in first place ).
I am refering the googlepay javascript demos here.
I do some search in the documents and under the "Card Parameters" find one option called "allowCreditCards". If it's true, then credit cards are allowed to be shown and selected option in popup window of googlepay but if that is false then only debit cards will be displayed.
Since I am in test account mode ( only test credit cards are provided by google ), I am not sure if I keep allowCreditCards=true then,
will it show only credit cards ? or will it show debit and credit both ?
Thanks in advance!
I tried by keeping allowCreditCards=true, then it shows four test cards and when I try with I keep allowCreditCards=false it shows no cards saying marchant supported cards are not available.
My dilemma is that for production setup, If I keep allowCreditCards=true then,
will it show only credit cards ? or will it show debit and credit both ?
My requirement is to only support credit cards.

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment. Are you able to give a bit more context on why you want to only accept credit cards?

we have different convenience fee for debit and credit card.
For example : credit card : 2% of payment amount. debit card: 1% of payment amount.
There is no way to identify which type of card the user is selecting. Also in recieved token response from google pay, there is no parameter which helps to identify card type. Hence I am thinking at the begining will show two seperate googlepay buttons. One for googlepay for debit and another for credit.
 
continued below...

When user click on , we will disable allowCreditCards: false. Hence only debit card of user will get display to user. And when user click on  , we will enable allowCreditCards: true. But here, along with credit card the popup window will also display user's debit cards too. And then user may select debit card in credit card popup window and we will apply wrong conv. fee to the user. Since there is no option like  "allowDebitCards: true/false". I am stuck in the implemention. Any other sulution you can suggest will help. Thanks!
